# How to send an email after User post the form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-email

i am beginner and used steps for sending email from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/ 
but i didn't accomplished to send email.

i want to send an email automatically using django email after a user submit the form . i am having a booking form and having email field in it after user post the form i want to send a email "Thankyou for your booking / your booking is placed ".

for eg

1. first name : Abubakar
2. Last name :Afzal
3. email : any@gmail.com

i want to take any@gmail.com and send email to it . after user post the form .

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**View.py**

```
     class BookingView(FormView):
         template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
         form_class = BookingForm
         models = Booking
         def form_valid(self, form):
             car_id = self.request.GET.get('car', '')
             car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
             car.is_available_car = False
             car.save()
             form.save()
             return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
        success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

**Forms.py**

```
      class BookingForm(ModelForm):

         class Meta:
            model = Booking
             widgets = {
             times_pick': TimePickerInput(),  }
             fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','book_car','contact_number','times_pick',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function called send_emails (or any name). and call taht function from within form_valid method. It will look something like this

```
   def form_valid(self, form):
        car_id = self.request.GET.get('car', '')
        car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
        car.is_available_car = False
        car.save()
        form.save()
        form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')

        #your function here
        send_emails(first_name, last_name, to_email)
```

and then define function something like this.

```
def send_emails(first_name, last_name, to_email):
    #get template
    htmly = get_template('email_templates/welcome.html')
    #create a context
    d = {'first_name':first_name, 'last_name':last_name}
    subject, from_email, to = 'Subject line', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to_email
    #pass the context to html template
    html_content = htmly.render(d)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Comment: i copied your code but its not working . can you edit your answer with my content please @ojas

Comment: d = {pass any context data that you want to send to html template} invalid syntax

Comment: I have updated the context.  This is the general idea.

Comment: name 'settings' is not defined
**after submit the form**

Comment: from django.conf import settings

Comment: SMTPServerDisconnected  after posting

Comment: This is something out of the scope of this issue and needs some research. stackoverflow or django docs can help you. I think we have solved the main issue of setting up email sending functionality.

Comment: Thank you sir  for helping me out

Comment: not a problem, googling the error is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class BookingView(FormView):
     template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
     form_class = BookingForm
     models = Booking
     def form_valid(self, form):
         car_id = self.request.GET.get('car', '')
         car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
         car.is_available_car = False
         car.save()
         form.save()
         subject = 'Thankyou for your booking / your booking is placed'
         message = 'Thankyou for your booking / your booking is placed'
         email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
         recipient_list = [any@gmail.com]
         send_mail( subject, message, email_from, recipient_list )
         return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).